Also delete images when deleting products via WooComerce REST API v3
I have a daily process that creates and deletes products from WooCommerce via API. However, when products are deleted, their associated images are not removed, resulting in a large number of unused images. How can I automate the deletion of these images when a product is removed?
I have tried with this script in code snippets with no success. it seems like the script is not bein executed.
add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'delete_product_images_on_remove' );

function delete_product_images_on_remove( $post_id ) {
    // Verifica si el post es un producto de WooCommerce
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) === 'product' ) {

        // Obtiene las imágenes de la galería de productos
        $product_gallery_ids = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', true );
        $product_gallery_ids = explode( ',', $product_gallery_ids );

        // Obtiene la imagen destacada del producto
        $featured_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

        // Borra la imagen destacada si existe
        if ( $featured_image_id ) {
            wp_delete_attachment( $featured_image_id, true );
        }

        // Borra cada imagen de la galería
        if ( is_array( $product_gallery_ids ) ) {
            foreach ( $product_gallery_ids as $image_id ) {
                wp_delete_attachment( $image_id, true );
            }
        }
    }
}


Welcome, JOrtega. Will you please translate code comments or remove them?

I've used this in the past - but please note that this only deletes the images when the product is deleted completely, not trashed
function delete_product_attachments( $post_id ) {
    // Only proceed if the post type is 'product'
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) === 'product' ) {
        // Get all attachments related to the post
        $attachments = get_children( array(
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
        ) );

        // Loop through and delete each attachment
        if ( ! empty( $attachments ) ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true );
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'delete_product_attachments' );

